# QRegExp does not recognize expression

Tags: regex, qt, qregexp

I have the following input:

> (&xxx-&yyyy) &pp_pp+&uuu

I'm trying to get all matches which starts with an & and are followed by any word character. 
E.g. above should yield to:

> &xxx
>   &yyyy
>   &pp_pp
>   &uuu

What I tried is:

```
 QRegExp rx;
 rx.setPattern("(&\\w+)+");
 rx.indexIn("(&xxx-&yyyy) &pp_pp+&uuu");
 QStringList variables;
 for(int i = 1; i < rx.captureCount(); i++)
 {
      variables.append(rx.cap(i));
 }
```

I just don't get any match. Where is my mistake?
If I have the above input rx.captureCount() is always 1.
I don't think it's my regex which is wrong, because I checked it on http://regexpal.com/ and there it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using:

```
 QStringList list;
 int pos = 0;

 while ((pos = rx.indexIn(str, pos)) != -1) {
      list << rx.cap(1);
      pos += rx.matchedLength();
 }
```

[Reference](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qregexp.html#capturedTexts)